# TypeError: data.data[i].caption is null Instagram api

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                $("#pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + "'></img></a>");
                $("#text").append("<p>"+data.data[i].caption.text+"</p>");


            }
        }
    });
});
```

am try to get Instagram feed api , the code working fine , but i have error `TypeError: data.data[i].caption is null` , feed text not show all i get only 3 form 20 element in json .

[data json link](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=17c05e938eeb42d37c330b814432e300)

Comment: please share the api response

Comment: check link api i put http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=17c05e938eeb42d37c330b814432e300 @brk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the response, you see that it simply means that there's no caption (for example, look at number 3)

Try something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $("#pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + "'></img></a>");
    if (data.data[i].caption === null) {
        $("#text").append("<p>No caption</p>");
    } else {
        $("#text").append("<p>"+data.data[i].caption.text+"</p>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in some of the caption is null like `data[3]` ,`data[4]` in the response. Do a null check before retrieving the `text` which is inside `caption` object

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      if (res.data[i].caption !== null) {
        console.log(res.data[i].caption.text);
      }

    }
```